# Combining all CSV files in a folder into one dataframe?

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R and so am trying my hand at remaking a workflow that I already use in a variety of programs all in R. The first step is combining all the CSV files in a folder into one dataframe. Each CSV has 220 rows, 1 header row, and 5 columns. I would like to combine it so it keeps the first header, and just adds all the data from the next CSV as new rows (i.e. combining 3 CSVs will result in a dataframe with 660 rows, 1 header row, and 5 columns).

The code I have only pulls one file and isn't combining all the files in the folder. Which part of the code do I need to change to make it happen? The code looks pretty similar to other code I have seen on here that seems to work for people, and I'm confused why it isn't working for me? I'm very new to this so any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
setwd()
  
# get a list of all the CSV files in the folder
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
  
# create an empty tibble to store the combined data
df_import <- tibble()
  
# loop through each CSV file and add it to the tibble
for (file in files) {
  # read in the CSV data as a tibble
  # using header = TRUE assumes the first row of each CSV file is a header with column names
  file_data <- read_csv(file)
  
  # add a column with the row names (i.e. the name of the CSV file)
  file_data <- file_data %>%
    mutate(file_name = file)
  
  # add the data to our overall tibble
  df_all <- df_import %>%
    bind_rows(file_data)
}
```

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read_csv))`

Comment: Change df_all to df_import.  Your existing code adds file_data to the bottom of the empty tibble df_import, and assigns it to df_all.  On the next loop, df_import is still empty (you have not added anything to it) and you assign the second iteration of file_data to df_all, overwriting the previous version.